# Existence of solution for a simple linear integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Does this linear integral equation defined on $[-a,a]$ have any nonconstant solution? I am more interested in the exsistence of solution rather than the solution itself. The boundary condition has two cases:

**Case $\bf(1)$ :** $~y(-a)=y(a)=b~~$ and

**Case $\bf(2)$ :** $~-y(-a)=y(a)=c~$.
$$\int_{-a}^{a}{  \frac{y(x)-y(x')}{(x-x')^2} ~~d x'}=0$$

I feel the solution, it exists at all, could be something simple. But I am not sure how to (dis)prove the exsistence or solve it.

Comment: $y(x)=b$ for all $x$ solves case 1).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I mean nontrivial solution. Edited.

Comment: How do you treat the singularity at $x=x'$? Especially at the interval ends $\pm a$ where you can not apply the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think we can assume the nominator should cancel out the singularity for any valid smooth solution.

Comment: How so? You can expand $y(x')=y(x)+y'(x)(x'-x)+\frac12y''(c_{x'})(x'-x)^2$, but what happens to the $y'(x)$ term?

Comment: @LutzLehmann For $-a<x<x$, the integral helps cancel the linear term by combining $x'>x$ and $x'<x$ parts. For $x=\pm a$, $y'(\pm a)=0$. Does this make it possible?